# Skip drive during boot?

Tags: boot, external-hard-drive

Okay so a while back I broke my screen on my laptop, so I cannot access the BIOS because I cannot see it. I have a few external hard drives that I keep connected to my laptop always, but when I reboot I have to unplug them so my laptop doesn't try to boot them. I was wondering if there was a file that I could put at the root of the drives that I don't want booted so the BIOS just skips over them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by making the partitions inactive, so they can be accessed but can't be boot.

1. Open up a command prompt and type `DISKPART`.
2. Type `LIST DISK`
3. Type `SELECT DISK n` (where `n` is the number of the drive)
4. Type `LIST PARTITION`
5. Type `SELECT PARTITION n` (where `n` is the number of the partition)
6. Type `INACTIVE`
7. Type `EXIT` to exit DISKPART
8. Type `EXIT` again to exit the command prompt

Comment: okay when i try to select the partition, i type in the corresponding number and it only says "no partition was selected" the partition i am trying to select does have a asterisk next to it

Comment: @sightofnick: If it shows an asterisk then it is selected, weird that it does give an error though...